# Angular - How to update table with new values

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with `ng-repeat`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>key</th>
      <th>value</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat = "i in data">
  <td>{{i.key}}</td>
  <td>{{i.value}}</td>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The `table` is populated with `data-ng-init`, when the user clicks on a button:

```
<button ng-click="getNewVals()">new values</button>
```

I get `json` with new `key-value`, my question is how to repopulate the table with the new values baes on the `key`? is there a angular way to do so?

Comment: show your javascript please and you made a typo you wrote ng-reapet instead of ng-repeat.

Comment: Yes it is just a typo, which part of my js?

Comment: It is over 1000 row, I am adding the http call, and the data.

Comment: btw you shouldn't have ng-repeat on tbody but on a tr tag that wrap the td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` is bound to the model you are iterating over. If you update the model, ng-repeat will re-draw. In your example, whenever `$scope.data` changes, the `ng-repeat` will update itself.

Comment: trying and posting the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way. It's good if you provide your JSON.

```js
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>key</th>
      <th>value</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat = "(key, val) in data">
  <td>{{key}}</td>
  <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in persons">{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="changeIt()">Change json</button>
<script>
    //1 module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //2 controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.persons = [
            {name:"Peter", "age": 23},
            {name:"Lina","age":26},
            {name:"Robert", "age":33}
        ];
        $scope.changeIt = function(){
            $scope.persons = [
                {name:"Larry",age: 59},
                {name:"Joseph", age: 63},
                {name:"Clara", age:71}
            ];
        }
    });
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you writing ng-reapet instead of ng-repeat

try this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>key</th>
      <th>value</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat = "i in data">
  <td>{{i.key}}</td>
  <td>{{i.value}}</td>
 </tbody>
</table>

<button ng-click="data.push({'key':1,'value':2})">new values</button>
```

Comment: you writing **ng-reapet** instead of **ng-repeat**

Comment: what is there in side  **getNewVals()** function. ?